# Exporting Bevel weights

Tags: scripting, export, bevel, file-format

Is there a file format that includes Bevel weights in the model? I am trying to export a Blender model to 3dsMax and then add use the bevel weight the same way in Max(Using the chamfer modifier, Max's equivalent). Otherwise, is there a way via python scripting to enter the edge bevel weight data into a CSV file that can work with the fbx?

For context, in Blender, if you add a bevel modifier and set the limit method to "Weight" you can control where and how much of a bevel there is on marked edges. To mark edges to be beveled, go to N key<Bevel Weight when selecting an edge. The weighted edges are then marked with Blue.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  One could write Python code to output a CSV file with the data; but I don't know how you'd get that into Max.

Comment: @MartyFouts Is there any documentation on using python to send the bevel weight data and to a CSV file?

Comment: There is no specific documentation but there are questions here that talk about the various bits of the problem.  You need to select the object, iterate over its vertices to get the bevel weights and on each iteration write a line to the CSV file with whatever data you need to read in Max.  Since I don't know Max at all, I have no idea what the file would look like.